# Without $f$ being specified, can we obtain $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

"Show that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = -\frac{1}{x(x+h)}$." is the problem I am looking at. In the solutions, the equality $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h}$ is given as the first step. How does this work? $f$ is not specified in the question. This question is given in the context of introducing differential calculus. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: This probably means that $f(x)=\frac 1 x$. In general it is not true for other functions.

Comment: It's perhaps a typo? Because there is not a mention of that in the question, though surely this is what was meant. Thank you!

Comment: @diomedesdata It could be a typo, or sometimes people overlook context like "For the following six questions, let $f(x)=1/x$." It would be worthwhile to check just to be sure.

Comment: $f$ *must* be specified.  You can easily come up with cases where that is isn't true.  Let  $f(x) = e^x$ or $f(x) = \sin x$ or $f(x)=7$ etc. It's just not true.  It is true for $f(x) = \frac 1x$ and though.

Comment: @EdwardH. As I show in my answer below, the manipulation was likely done using partial fractions to make the change on the right side. It doesn't depend directly on what $f\left(x\right)$ is.

Comment: @fleablood As I commented to EdwardH, the right hand side manipulation doesn't directly depend on $f$ but, rather, can be done simply using partial fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manipulation done only depends on $h \neq 0$, without it requiring any special conditions on $f\left(x\right)$, including that it even be differentiable, even though only certain functions of $f\left(x\right)$ will work, as indicated in the comments and the answer by [H Huang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/604218/h-huang). I suspect what I show below was the intent of the solution step.

To see how to make the change without knowing $f\left(x\right)$, treat $x$ as a variable and $h$ as a constant, and note the partial fraction decomposition of the right side of what you're trying to show may be written as

$$\cfrac{-1}{x\left(x + h\right)} = \cfrac{A}{x} + \cfrac{B}{x + h} = \cfrac{Ax + Ah + Bx}{x\left(x + h\right)} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Putting the $2$ terms with $x$ together, then comparing coefficients of $x$ and the constant term, we thus have that

$$A + B = 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$Ah = -1 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

From \eqref{eq3}, we get that $A = \frac{-1}{h}$, so \eqref{eq2} then gives $B = \frac{1}{h}$. Substituting these values into \eqref{eq1} gives

$$-\cfrac{1}{x\left(x + h\right)} = \cfrac{-1}{hx} + \cfrac{1}{h\left(x + h\right)} = \cfrac{\frac{1}{x + h} - \frac{1}{x}}{h} \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

This shows that the right hand sides of the $2$ equations in the question for $\frac{f\left(x + h\right) - f\left(x\right)}{h}$ are equivalent to each other.

Note it's simpler & easier to see this relationship going the other way, by having both terms use a common denominator, simplifying and dividing by the common $h$ factor to get

$$\cfrac{1}{h}\left(\cfrac{1}{x + h} - \cfrac{1}{x}\right) = \cfrac{1}{h}\left(\cfrac{x - \left(x + h\right)}{x\left(x + h\right)}\right) = \cfrac{1}{h}\left(\cfrac{-h}{x\left(x + h\right)}\right) = -\cfrac{1}{x\left(x + h\right)}  \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Comment: That's a cool solution. Why must we set A + B = 0, rather than setting it to -1 and setting the other term to 0?

Comment: @diomedesdata You need to do it the way I show it to get the result they show. If you did what you suggest instead, then you would get $A = 0$ and $B = \frac{-1}{x}$, which just gets you back to the LHS of $\left(1\right)$.

Comment: You are welcome. The operation they did was not obvious to you & several other people here. I believe they should have even just simply mentioned something like "using partial fractions, we get". However, if you see something like this again, you now know how it was likely done.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the definition of the derivative of $f(x)$ is $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Given that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = -\frac{1}{x(x+h)}$, that means that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}-\frac{1}{x(x+h)}$. The limit $\lim_{h \to 0}-\frac{1}{x(x+h)}$ is pretty easy to evaluate; it's equal to $-\frac{1}{x^2}$. 
Thus, $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.
$\frac{1}{x^2}$ happens to be the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$, so reversing the 
definition of the derivative, $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$.

Thus, even without $f(x)$ being given, from the fact that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=-\frac{1}{x(x+h)}$, we can find $f(x)$. Knowing $f(x)$, it's not hard to see where $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{h}$ comes from.

Comment: Thank you! I did this line of reasoning as well, so I understand how it fits together. To me though, the structure of the question seemed to imply I had to go LHS -> RHS through some identity or other. I thought I may have forgotten some inverse law or something of this kind. Regardless, thank you again for your answer!

Comment: @diomedesdata As I show in my solution, you can just simply use partial fractions to directly go between the $2$ RHS expressions, without needing the step of doing anything with the LHS, including determining any particular value of $f\left(x\right)$.